# How to figure out which block device the OS (Linux) is running from

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a system that has a set of Self-encrypting drives (SEDs)  with OS (Ubuntu on one and CentOS on the another and rest blank) installed on each of them. I'm trying to write an application that allows me to 'lock/unlock' the drives using TCG security commands. So when I'm in ubuntu, I lock all the other drives; and when I am in CentOS I lock the Ubuntu OS disk.

My problem right now is, from Ubuntu how do I figure out which disk (sda /sdb/ sdc ???) the current running kernel is sourced. It needs to be a generic logic so that the technique works for a ubuntu / ubuntu installation pair, hence just detecting the centOS partitions will not help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try lsblk or fdisk command

Comment: Keep in mind, bootloader can sit on one disk, kernel on another, and root filesystem - on third.